# Obtener carpeta de usuario para cualquier usuario en Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

recientemente me he encontrado con una funcionalidad que parece no estar implementada actualmente en python.

Actualmente podemos obtener la carpeta del usuario activo de varias formas (hablando de linux):

```
import os
os.environ("HOME")
os.path.expanduser("~/")
```

¿Pero qué pasa si a nuestro script lo han llamado con sudo?

```
$sudo python my_script.py
import os
print(os.environ["HOME"]) => /root
print(os.path.expanduser("~/")) => /root/
print(os.geteuid()) => 0
print(os.getenv("HOME")) => /root
print(os.getenv("USER")) => root
print(os.getenv("SUDO_UID")) => 1000
print(os.getenv("SUDO_USER")) => dev
```

Antes de implementar mi propia función para obtener el la carpeta de un usuario me gustaría saber si alguien conoce la forma más pythonica o si alguien lo ha implementado ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando esta librería https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html# he encontrado la solución, no obstante con lo anterior mencionado se podía....

```
import os
os.path.expanduser("~{0}".format(os.getenv("SUDO_USER")))
```

Pero con pathlib se puede hacer más pythónico y bonito

```
from pathlib import Path
Path("~").expanduser().resolve()
Path.home().resolve()
Path("~{0}".format(os.getenv("SUDO_USER"))).resolve()
```